# Flexbox: how to add margin / vertical spacing for the case there is more than one row?

Tags: css, flexbox

[here is the codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXmpxb)

[image]

I want to add vertical spacing *ONLY* to elements between line 1 and line 2. Alternatively, only to between line 1 and line 2, and line 2 and line 3.

The flex items are random, so the amount, size of each, is dynamic.

I cannot add margins to all, because that would ruin the layout in case there is no second row at all.

HTML

```
<div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="flexItem">a a a aaaaaaa a ax</div>
  <div class="flexItem">bbbx</div>
  <div class="flexItem">c c  c c c cx</div>
  <div class="flexItem">note: random amount of flex items</div>
    <div class="flexItem">amount can very...</div>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/>
<div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="flexItem">a a a aaaaaaa a ax</div>
  <div class="flexItem">bbbx</div>
  <div class="flexItem">c c  c c c cx</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flexContainer{
  background-color: salmon;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 300px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexItem{
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Browsersupport: only newest cutting edge browsers are supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can

- Add some `margin-bottom` to the first and last `.flex-item`s.
- Align all flex items to top with `align-items: flex-start` or `align-self: flex-start`.
- Add a negative `margin-bottom` to `.flexContainer` in order to counteract the margin after the last line.
- Place the `.flexContainer` inside a wrapper with `overflow: hidden`.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.flexContainer {
  background-color: salmon;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: -20px; /* 25-20 = 5 */
}
.flexItem {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.flexItem:first-child, .flexItem:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flexContainer">
    <div class="flexItem">a a a aaaaaaa a ax</div>
    <div class="flexItem">bbbx</div>
    <div class="flexItem">c c  c c c cx</div>
    <div class="flexItem">note: random amount of flex items</div>
    <div class="flexItem">amount can very...</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flexContainer">
    <div class="flexItem">a a a aaaaaaa a ax</div>
    <div class="flexItem">bbbx</div>
    <div class="flexItem">c c  c c c cx</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Toskan The margins to the first and last items will add space after the first and last lines. Then, the negative margin of the container and the `overflow: hidden` of the wrapper will hide the margin after the last line (which may be the same as the first one).